# read.WSdata Error in data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to do the Landsat 8 example at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/water/vignettes/Landsat8.html example. I get stuck at the read.WSdata example where I get the error `Error in data.frame(date = unique(WSdata$date), radiation_sum = tapply(WSdata$radiation,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0` I am using my own data - NOT the data provided in the example.

My csv file has been organized exactly as the example dataset ("INTA.csv"). The only difference I have noticed between the datasets is that mine has a datetime every 15min and the example dataset has datetime every hour.

Here is my code.

```
`rm(list=ls()) 
library(water)
aoi<-createAoi(topleft=c(385387,4776577),
bottomright=c(414825,4749526), EPSG = 32612)
raw_data_folder <- system.file("rossfrk072616", package="water")
image <- loadImage(path=raw_data_folder, aoi=aoi, sat="L8")
image.SR <- loadImageSR(path=raw_data_folder, aoi=aoi)
plot(image)
plot(image.SR)
csvfile<-system.file("rossfrk072616","FTHI_L8_1.csv",package="water")`
```

I am also assuming we use the original MTL file and NOT the surface reflectance MTL file, which when you download from the ESPA gives the same name of the mtl file as the original?

MTLfile <- system.file("rossfrk072616", 
   "LC08_L1TP_039030_20160726_20170221_01_T1_MTL.txt", package="water")
   `WeatherStation <- read.WSdata(WSdata = csvfile,datetime.format =  "%Y/%m/%d 
    %H:%M",columns = c("datetime", "temp","RH", "pp", "radiation", 
    "wind"),lat=43.07138, long= -112.4311, elev=1354.5, height= 2.5, MTL = 
    MTLfile)`

After I run the read.WSdata I get the error

```
Error in data.frame(date = unique(WSdata$date), radiation_sum = 
tapply(WSdata$radiation,: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Comment: can't speak to the specifics of MTL, but tapply : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 -  suggests 1 row is called for but isn't there, i.e. the data for the columns = c("datatime", & etc.

Comment: I was unable to find any errors with the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is error is related to different formats for the date. In your first attempt the `date.format` was set to `'%Y/%m/%d'`.

Also, you can directly specify the file in the `read.WSdata()` function, e.g.:

`WeatherStation <- read.WSdata(WSdata = 'FTHI_L8_1.csv', date.format = "%d/%m/%Y",
                  lat=43.07138, long= -112.4311, elev=1354.5, height= 2.5,
                  MTL = MTLfile)`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I was not able to get the code from the website to function with my dataset. However, I was able to read my weather station data with the following code. `WeatherStation <- read.WSdata(WSdata = csvfile, date.format = "%d/%m/%Y",
                  lat=43.07138, long= -112.4311, elev=1354.5, height= 2.5,
                  MTL = MTLfile)`

Answer (score 0):

I used my data and it worked well

```
library(water) 

aoi <- createAoi(topleft = c(810927, 2134059), bottomright = c( 272751,1985845), 
                     EPSG = 32616)
plot(aoi)

csvfile <- system.file("extdata", "datos.csv", package="water")

MTLfile <- system.file("extdata", "L8.MTL.txt", package="water")


ws<- read.WSdata(WSdata = csvfile, date.format = "%d/%m/%Y", time.format="%H:%M:%S", cf= 
                  c(1,1,1),lat=18.094, long= -89.462, elev=279, height= 2,  MTL = 
                  MTLfile, columns=c("date" = 1, "time" = 2, "radiation" = 3,"wind" = 4, 
                  "RH" = 5, "temp" = 6, "rain" = 7))
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.